# Move existing images present in Media folders of Orchard to CDN

Tags: azure, web-applications, orchardcms, cdn

We have an existing site that uses Media folder of Orchard to store images, and being used heavily in web pages. Now we want to share the Media folder to be shared across two different Web Apps(one is production site and the other is a Staging).

In some of the cases where content developer adds an image to site, it is actually stored on the file system in the production, but we miss these images in our Mirror site, so we have to do a manual copy.

Currently we are thinking to store the media files in Azure blob storage, so that I can share the images between Production and Staging, had anyone that? if yes, please share your thoughts

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are two apps sharing the same database as well? If not, that must be the problem. In Orchard 1.9 and higher, stores images as media items in database too.

Comment: yes, two apps are sharing the same DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Microsoft Azure Media Storage` module to enable storing the assets in Azure Blobs.

There is a setup process for this [described in docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-Windows-Azure-Blob-Storage).

The connection string will happily work shared between multiple projects.

If you have tenants then they can have their own isolated Storage accounts as well (and therefore their own custom domains).

When you enable it though it won't automatically copy the existing assets over to your Azure Blob Storage. I think there is a tool called AzCopy which you can use to move files in and out of cloud storage.

FYI although it is a kind of CDN, by default Azure Blob Storage is just stored in one data center, replicated 3 times. There is actually a different product offering on [Azure for a true CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cdn/) if you want it to be replicated to points around the world to speed up asset delivery for global users but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for based on your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a blob storage with media between production and staging just works.
I regularly copy my production site to my local machine and run the site locally and see all images.

Maybe watch out that you only add images add the production site, not sure which references there are to the file in the Orchard Database.

Have a look in the database, or just try it out and let us know.